# Why typeorm (in Nestjs) throws error in transformer?

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I have an entity:

```
@Entity()
export class MyEntity {
  ...,

  @Column({
    type: 'int',
    transformer: {
      from(value: number): Faction {
        return Factions.getById(value)
      },
      to(value: Faction): number {
        return value.id
      }
    }
  })
  Member: Faction
}
```

I set a value and update it:

```
...
myEntity.Member = Factions.findById(1) //console.log(myEntity.Member) - is ok (not undefined)
await repository.update(myEntity.id, myEntity)
```

I encounter an error during the update:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')
      135 |       },
      136 |       to(value: Faction): number {
    > 137 |         return value.id
          |                      ^
      138 |       }
      139 |     }
      140 |   })
```

Why does this happen? When I update other columns, it works fine.

*Nestjs and typescript is latest versions*